# Navigating to the same route cancelled by the canDeactivate guard is failing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

If i try to navigate to a route that is cancelled by the `canDeactivate` guard, its not happening . Is their any workaround for this issue ?

I have a component with a form and if their are any unsaved changes and if we try to navigate away, we are showing a bootstrap confirm popup in the `canDeactivate` guard. If we select OK then we navigate to that same route again, which is not happening. Is their any workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spent 3 hours trying to figure this out for myself.
It's a bug with @angular/router version 3.2.

I fixed it by downgrading to version 3.1 and reinstalling the package.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying, but checkout this:

```
canDeactivate() {
  return dialogService.confirm('Discard unsaved changes?');
}
```

This should work for you. Check out this [Doc](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/route_guards.html)

Comment: Avnesh,  I looked into the doc that you gave . I am sending the plunker link wich i saw in that doc itself .Change the version of angular & router in the system.config.js to `var angularVersion = '2.2.1';
var rcVersion = '3.2.1';` and try it . The same issue is happening .
http://plnkr.co/edit/w1NCkGs0Tv5TjivYMdvt?p=preview